# how to define permission for a specific application in android?

Tags: android, permissions

I wanna define permission for specific application and I don't want to access any applications to it.

What should I do? Do I set it with `protectionLevel:signature`?
If I should use `protectionLevel:signature`, How can I define key for other applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `protectionLevel` to signature only apps signed with the same key will be able to get that permission. So, if you sign all your applications with the same key, all of your applications will be able to use that permission. As long as you take care to keep your private key to yourself, no other app will be able to get this permission.

Comment: Thanks, I looked for about protectionLevel but I didn't find any thing. Could you give sample code me?

Comment: Android reference has some info on this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#declaring http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel

Comment: yeah, I did study it. I wanna know about signature. How can I use or code and make same key for all of my applications?

Comment: You don't have to do anything special, the framework will handle it automatically. Just declare the permission, and the sign your apps with the same key. Try it.

Comment: what is mean same key? It's name of permission or when I get permission I'll get it's key?     I don't know about it, please write a sample.

Comment: 'Key' refers to the key you use to sign your applications (APKs) as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html